Should you be able to opt out of points and badges?
I don't want to receive points or badges or take part in an infantile game. Is there a way to stop receiving these and just have your questions answered?


Is there a way to stop receiving these and just have your questions answered?

No, that's a part of the site mechanics.
Upvotes and downvotes are supposed to be a measure of how "useful" your content is. The idea is that if the post is "useful", you upvote it, and if it's "not useful" or even "harmful", you downvote it.
This feature originated on StackOverflow, the first and the biggest site on the network, which is a Q/A site for questions about computer programming and software development.
It was designed to solve the problem that had existed on other online forums of the time. There were a lot of good questions that had good answers, but for the most part, they were buried inside long discussion threads flooded with messages barely related to the original topic. One would have to spend a lot of time finding the answer and even more time telling good advice apart from bad.
By giving people the ability to vote for good answers and questions, and by curtailing all discussion that was not relevant to the question, the site mechanics tried to fix that particular problem. Judging by the fact that StackOverflow quickly became the most popular site for programming advice on the Internet, it worked for that particular area.
Many people are disappointed with certain aspects of this system, including the concept of "reputation score" (the measure of how many "useful" answers you have given or "useful" questions you asked), "badges", and the whole gamification aspect this all inevitably entails.
One of the sites on the network, MathOverflow (Q/A for professional mathematicians), has implemented technical measures to hide the participants' reputation scores from the visitors. Still, it's there, along with the "badges", and if you visit the user's profile, you are still able to see them.
I, personally, don't pay a lot of attention to these scores and badges, although I should admit it feels nice to see this green icon pop up every now and then. Theoretically, we could have implemented a technical measure like this here, but this would require quite a lot of effort and would not be done anyway without discussion with other participants. There might be some who like it this way.
In my opinion, the easiest ways to deal with it would be:

Stop paying attention to the reputation score and badges, and pretend they don't exist (the editor's choice).
There are numerous ways to customize the appearance of virtually any web site just in your own browser to your own liking. The technical term for this is "user stylesheet". If you have some basic web programming skills, you might want to spend a couple of days developing a user stylesheet that would make them invisible to you, or hire a college kid who would be able to do it for you in a couple hours.

Yet another option might be marking your questions and answers as "community wiki". It will stop the votes given for these questions and answers from counting towards your reputation score.

My answer is to always reply in the form of comments, not answers, which I will do from now on.

Please don't do that. Comments are intended to drive the attention to problems with answers and questions, or ask for clarifications. They are a pain to read and to write, don't get indexed by search engines, and defy the purpose of the site of being a repository of knowledge about Russian in Q/A format. We don't allow excessive discussion in comments. I realize you might dislike certain aspects of the site mechanics, but that's how this site works. Thank you for understanding.
